# JSON.Net ignore fields on serialization for 3rd party class

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using a 3rd party class for Date range handling (Itenso.TimePeriod), and I want to serialize these objects with JSON.Net. There are many fields in this class that I don't want to be serialized, to keep the JSON small. For my own classes I use the `[JSonIgnore]` attribute, but I don't want to fork this 3rd party component, just to add `[JSonIgnore]`s to some of its fields.
I know the `[OnSerializing]` callbacks, but these would also require to change the 3rd party class.
Of course, I could create some DTO classes that leave out the properties that I don't want to be serialized, but maybe there's a more elegant way?

Comment: I'd say the best solution is DTO class. But you could create a JsonConverter as well.   Here's an example: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Comment: [`CustomJsonConverter<Itenso.TimePeriod>`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm) would be the way to go, but we can't really answer without a more concrete example.  Possibly useful: [Registering a custom JsonConverter globally in Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19510532), [How to deserialize a unix timestamp (μs) to a DateTime from JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19971494/3744182).  One approach would be to create a DTO for `TimePeriod` then convert to, and serialize, the DTO inside the converter.

Comment: The elegant way is working with DTO. Is the flexible way, and the correct one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell Json.NET to ignore properties in a 3rd-party object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749509/how-can-i-tell-json-net-to-ignore-properties-in-a-3rd-party-object)